# How to protect my gear after moving to a humid area?

Tags: equipment-protection, environmental-dangers, humidity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What precautions should I take when taking a camera into humid conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/what-precautions-should-i-take-when-taking-a-camera-into-humid-conditions)

I recently moved from a desert to a more humid area. What kinds of things to I need to know to keep my photo gear protected from the humidity?

I have lenses, cameras, and flashes, plus a whole bunch of stuff like tripods and the like.