# What type of camera, camera equipment or techniques should I use for prolonged high humidity shooting?

Tags: equipment-damage, humidity

I work for a greenhouse. We are working on getting a website up and I need to take photos of ALL of our plants in 3 different sizes. We have 244 different types of herbs and scented geraniums. Needless to say, it is not a quick process to photograph all of these plants.

The most convenient place for me to do the photographing is IN the greenhouses. It is, of course, warm and very humid in there. How can I take photos, for hours at a time, in this environment without damaging the camera?

Comment: This should provide much if not all of the info you are looking for: [What precautions should I take when taking a camera into humid conditions?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/what-precautions-should-i-take-when-taking-a-camera-into-humid-conditions)

Comment: I would place the camera in a plastic bag and drop it in the greenhouse already the previous day. Let it warm thoroughly to the temperature, and also keep the camera in for as many days as you need to.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a [weather-sealed camera](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?weatherproof=1&by=feature&lensattachment=Mount) and lens. What you are asking is not that stressful for the right camera. I have spend weeks in the jungle without any problems, at least you can get out of the greenhouse to change lenses!

If the quality does not matter, you can actually go with a [waterproof model](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?waterproof=1&by=feature) but I suggest the weather-sealed one because you can get a good [weather-sealed macro lens](http://www.neocamera.com/search_lens.php?weatherproof=1&macro=1&by=feature) to get nice close-ups of each specimen.

For this to work you need to pick a camera and lens from the links above that match in terms of mount and sensor-size coverage. And, yes you *must* use a weather-sealed lens with a weather-sealed camera, otherwise the whole thing is not weather-sealed.

Comment: I'd love a weather sealed DSLR but, I don't see my employer being able to outfit me with that.  

Would a water proof camera be more unlikely to get internal moisture than other cameras in a humid environment just because of its case- Provided precautions are taken to avoid things like lens fog?

My concern is that the humidity or temp changes could still cause internal problems, within a water proof case, & then it wouldn't be any better off than a camera without a water proof case..I’d hate to promise my boss that a water proof camera will solve our problem & then find out otherwise.

Comment: A waterproof camera is completely sealed, so no it would not have more problems if you let it warm up slowly. Usually people bring it in a ziplock bag and take it out a few minutes later and that lets you avoid condensation.

Answer (score 0):

If a weather-sealed camera isn't an option, you could use a rain sleeve accompanied by a UV filter. In terms of avoiding condensation on the lens, your best bet is to keep the camera warmer than the air.