# How to better protect gear on snowy / rainy weather

Tags: equipment-protection, weather

I live in a very rainy / snowy part of the world. This is not a very good thing if you are a photographer (specially with your shiny new gear) since you want to take it out but might be prevented from doing so from the amount of rain/snow.

Besides the common usage of the [ziploc to prevent condensation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/what-precautions-should-i-take-when-taking-a-camera-into-humid-conditions) and your camera bag, what else can I do while shooting to prevent accumulation of water snow on lenses and body?

PS. Camera and one lens is weather sealed but not the rest.

Comment: Are you having specific problems? With my weather-sealed gear, there is nothing I need to do but keep shooting :) ...and I too live in a very snowy part of the world....something I am strongly considering changing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a rain sleeve like the one shown [here at Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/cover-Camera-Protector-Canon-Pentax/dp/B004GTIYVS/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1357308160&sr=8-4)?  Very cheap solution to your problem...

[image]