# What do I need to be aware of to shoot a swim meet?

Tags: canon-50d

I am going to be shooting a swim meet for my yearbook, and the local swim club. This will be my first time shooting a meet. What do I need to know? Are there certain vantage points that will give a better photo (I will have access to all of the pool, including the deck and stands)? Are there precautions to take with my gear, other than simply keeping it dry?
I will be using a Canon 50d with 18-55 and 75-300mm lenses. I also have a hot-shoe flash, but I don't know if it is a good idea to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Indoor pools are very humid environments, so take a look at: [What precautions should I take when taking a camera into humid conditions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/what-precautions-should-i-take-when-taking-a-camera-into-humid-conditions)
- Shoot RAW as the white balance will typically be very tricky and the light temperature overall will be terrible
- If your lens has a panning setting, use it
- Become familiar with the different types of strokes, each one has a different angle that will work best for photos
- Push that ISO up on your 50D, potentially 3200 or 6400 if necessary
- Consider a f/2.8 or better telephoto. I would love to have the Canon 135 f/2.0 L for example for this use
- Burst mode, AI Servo, 1/250th sec or faster if possible
- Have fun, use wide angles as well, don't get too wet :)