# How to prevent my waterproof camera from condensation?

Tags: lens

I recently bought a HP C-150w for my vacations and the first time I've used it in water it got condensation on the lens as soon as I removed it from water.

I've been reading about how to prevent this to happen with cases, but none with waterproof cameras.

the condensations is on the inside, impossible to clean...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What precautions should I take when taking a camera into humid conditions?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/what-precautions-should-i-take-when-taking-a-camera-into-humid-conditions)

Comment: I think the specific situation of this being a waterproof camera makes that a related question, but not a duplicate.

Comment: I think you should return the camera.  If the condensation is on the inside, there is water on the inside, which means your camera is not waterproof.  Unless you took it beyond its limit of 10ft, then it's your mistake.

Answer (score 6):

That's a pretty common issue with some waterproof cameras. To eliminate the internal humidity you can try storing it (with the battery and card slots empty and open) with silica gel packs, or using a hair dryer on it (also with the battery and card slots open) for a while just before use.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do is to return the camera, as this kind of camera is not supposed to accumulate condensation inside. Another option is to keep the camera near to an incandescent light ( electric bulb) to let water evaporate.